# Rails remember_token session not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am learning it through Michel Hartl's reference doc available on the internet. However i ran into a problem during sign-in of users, I suspect the before_save is not calling the create_remember_token method. I am trying to debug this issue from a very long time. My code is as follows:

user.rb file:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime        not null
#  updated_at      :datetime        not null
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  username        :string(255)
#  remember_token  :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def to_param
username
end
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username
has_secure_password


before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

private

def create_remember_token
 self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
end
```

session_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
 @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def signed_in?
 !current_user.nil?
end

private

def user_from_remember_token
  remember_token = cookies[:remember_token]
  User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token) unless remember_token.nil?
end   
end
```

sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new

end

def create
    user=User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to "/@/#{params[:session][:username]}"
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "Login failed! Please try again!"
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy

end
end
```

Please help me and let me know as to where the problem exists.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted this question a year ago.
Now I am using the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for authentication. Everything is working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The before_save callbacks should only be called when the user is created (ie. when they sign up, not when they sign in).  You don't show the whole sign-up/user creation flow in your code sample, but i assume it exists.

You can test whether create_remember_token is called (when the user is created) by running this command from the Rails console:

```
User._save_callbacks.select { |cb| cb.kind.eql?(:before) }.collect(&:filter).include?(:create_remember_token)
```

That should return true if and only if the create_remember_token function is being run on save.  More details in the 'Debugging callbacks' section of the [Callbacks API Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

If the callback is called during the signup flow, the remember_token should be saved to the DB then.  You can verify that by inspecting the user with the Rails console (User.last, after creating your test user).

What does your sign-up/user creation flow look like?  What repro steps produce the problem you're describing?

Comment: user_controller.rb:                                                                  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @user=User.new
  end
  
  def show
   @user=User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  end
  
  def create
   @user=User.new(params[:user])
   a=params[:username]
   if @user.save
     flash[:success] = "Welcome to SocialCrow! Please verify your email address!"
     redirect_to "/@/#{params[:user][:username]}"
   else
    render 'new'
   end
  end
end

Comment: so u mean to say that i generate this token during the signup process

Comment: yes.  The 'if @user.save ...' call in your Create function triggers the before_save callbacks, including create_remember_token.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem that you are having during sign in?

The reason I ask is that the create_remember_token method is not supposed to be called during the sign-in process. It gets called when the user is saved (sign-up).

The sign-in process just fetches the token from the users table and copies it into the permanent cookie. The sign-in process looks roughly like this:

sign_in user -->  session_helper.rb -->  def sign_in(user) -->  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token  --> back to session_controller.rb --> redirect_to ...

Answer (score 0):

You might have not used csrf meta tag in your layout. Try removing ' protect from forgery ' in application_controller.rb in controllers folder. Then try running the app again, if it works then you didnt add tags to your layout.